# RPM vs Speed X-Trail T31 2010

Tags: transmission, gears, cvt-transmission, x-trail

I'm running a Nissan X-Trail T31 2010. It has a CVT gear box and when I'm running on 80kmph, the rpm is around 2.3.

Is this normal or are there any issues when shifting gears?

I'm asking that because I don't feel any gear shifting is happening. Please help me with this

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Do you  know what a CVT is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your car has a CVT gear box, that stands for [Continuously Variable Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuously_variable_transmission). A CVT constantly changes gear ratios as you drive to maintain a continuous engine rpm, you won't feel gear changes because there are no gears to change.

There's nothing wrong, it's how it's meant to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read some articles as well. But I thought there should be an any kind of feeling. Now I confirmed. :)

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, CVT has continuous gear ratios. You won't feel jerky shifts at all with a CVT.

How to test if your CVT is working properly: drive on a highway at below the speed limit, then suddenly floor the accelerator pedal to cause quick acceleration up to the maximum permitted speed. You should hear the engine sound increase in pitch and in intensity, as the engine starts to rotate faster to provide the required power.

Then release the accelerator pedal. You should stop hearing the high-pitched loud engine sound.

If your car has an RPM gauge (like what you said in the question), the test is accompanied by the RPMs going to near the redline during the test and then going back to normal after the test. However, some CVT cars may lack the RPM gauge.